# how do I get out of this itemBuilder and forEach problem?

Tags: mobile, flutter, dart

```
    child:new ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 4,
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          itemBuilder:  (BuildContext context, int index) {

           NewsData.news.forEach((n)=> _getPostWidgets(n));


          }),
```

I just have a empty page and that's the only error
 "This function has a return type of 'Widget', but doesn't end with a return statement."

If I only do

```
    child:new ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 4,
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          itemBuilder:  (BuildContext context, int index) {

           return _getPostWidgets(n1));


          }),
```

n1 working 4 times its cool but it won't let me put a return in the first code.I tried throwing itembuilder by creating a different function but it didn't work or i did wrong

can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `itemBuilder` will be called for each line of your `listView`. Just it appears on screen...

You should call `_getPostWidgets(NewsData.news[index]);`

For best code, you should use the size of your list as the size of `listView`:

```
    child:new ListView.builder(
          itemCount: NewsData.news.length,
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          itemBuilder:  (BuildContext context, int index) {

           return _getPostWidgets(NewsData.news[index]));


          }),
```

Comment: NewsData.news.length its working length times true but i have a list like newTile,newsDescription blabla i need to do for each a in list run _getPostWidgets(a) something like that i have to send my list variables to function
bad english and newbie sorry if I misunderstood

Comment: That's why you have `_getPostWidgets(NewsData.news[index]))` so you run the same as `NewsData.news.forEach((n)=> _getPostWidgets(n));`